# C++ Run Failed: Exit value 2 - What's wrong with my code?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that converts roman numerals to arabic numbers, and vice versa, and my output is tripping when it executes the code below. (Run Failed: Exit value 2).

The user inputs a string value and the code makes sure the numerals are upper case before trying to locate it in the units array and passing it's index value to the value of arabic. I'm new to C++ so any input is appreciated. I believe the for/if loop is my problem but I have no idea how to fix it?

```
//roman to arabic
    int toArabic() {
        transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), ::toupper);
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(units); i++) {
            if (input == units[i]) {
                arabic = i;
            }
        }
        cout << arabic << endl;
        }
```

//main class

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

while (!cin.eof()) {
    getline(cin, input);
    if (isdigit(input[0])) {
       toRoman();
       input.clear();
       roman.clear();
    }
    else if (isalpha(input[0])) {
        toArabic();
        input.clear();
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
    }
}
```

/// units array (similar array for tens, hundreds etc)

```
string units[] = {"", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX"};
```

Sorry if the answer is obvious/my code is bad, I've spent hours on this and still can't figure out my problem

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? If not, go ahead, read about it and try!

Comment: Where is units defined?

Comment: What is `units`? If it's an array, then the number of elements is `sizeof(units)/sizeof(units[0])`. If it's something else, then the size is something else. In any case, we'd need a [complete test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to figure out what's wrong with your real code.

Comment: Units is an array of roman numerals 1-9 - 
string units[] = {"", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX"};

Comment: @Tommo `sizeof(array)` will not return the right value because it returns the space the array takes up in bytes. You should use [`std::extent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) if you need to iterate like this and cannot use ranged based for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int toArabic() means your function will return an integer - int.  But your function returns nothing.  Possibly that is what your compiler is complaining about.  Change to void toArabic() and see if that clears the compiler error.  void in this context means returns nothing.

Or is this a runtime error?  What is the output when you build this program?